# Does someone have the java library for fuzzy description logic reasoner Delorean?

Tags: java, owl, fuzzy-logic

The fuzzy reasoner `Delorean` was open to the public once, I believe. But now nothing was there ([Docs1](http://webdiis.unizar.es/~fbobillo/delorean)), no java documentation. What happened? Or it was never an open-source project? I found a link ([Docs2](http://www.webdiis.unizar.es/fbobillo/delorean)) in their new paper "`Delorean`: a reasoner for fuzzy OWL 2", but I couldn't open it.

I was trying to test the usability of `fuzzyDL` and `Delorean`, but I found `fuzzyDL` somewhat unreasonable, it keeps saying `"Nullpointer exception"` where fetching the query results, no matter what the queries were. I don't understand why. Can someone give a hint please?

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone give a hint please?

Hint:  Contact the author by email.

There is a downloads link on the main site at http://webdiis.unizar.es/~fbobillo/delorean, but it is going to an error page.  (And if you believe what the Wayback Machine says, that link has *never* worked!)

The phrase "open to the public" is not meaningful.  If the code was (really) published as Open Source at some point, then it should still be Open Source.  A genuine Open Source license cannot be rescinded.  On the other hand, I cannot find any evidence that DeLorean was ever published as open source.

---

If something says `NullPointerException`, that is evidence of a bug, not "unreasonableness".  However, that bug could be in your code rather than the code you are trying to use; e.g. if you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, I should've contacted the author.

Comment: Late Comment, but for fuzzyDL you should have consider the README first because it says that you need to install the gurobi tool. If you dont, then you get some `NullPointerException`. Bad software engineering I know, since fuzzyDL could warn you about the missing dependency, but its free code.